# Bootstrap - Prevent Alert From Closing Through JavaScript Alert Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Kindly look at my code:

```
$('#myPanel').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
    //  insert code here
});
```

I tried `return false` inside, and even passed `event` as parameter in `function(){}` and performed `event.preventDefault()`, but it still won't stop the alert from being closed. I need to prevent the alert from being closed in case some conditions that I will put will not be satisfied.

Comment: You can overload 'closed.bs.alert' function .

closed.bs.alert= $(function(){
  // your code here ..
})

Comment: or share some more detail .. to review the issue

Comment: Have you checked if the event has a `preventDefault` method attached to it?

Comment: @anied , I edit the question to include my trying of event's `preventDefault`

Comment: Have you tried listening to the `close.bs.alert` event instead of the `closed.bs.alert` one? From the docs, that one is triggered _after_ the alert is already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
$('#myPanel [data-dismiss]').on('click', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Instead of hooking into bootstrap's event we hook into the user's click of the dismiss button, and prevent bootstrap's event from triggering.

Comment: Yeah, it did worked! Thank you so much. I'm still a newbie with JavaScript so I did not know that I can prevent hooking bootstrap's event if my conditions are not met. Awesome!

Comment: Cool! It's worth noting that if the user can close the alert any other ways (e.g. by pressing the 'Esc' key) then this will not work. I'm not familiar with boostrap, but if you can only close the alert by clicking the X button, this solution should be fine.

Comment: @edmund-reed , what if I'm inside an AJAX function, how can I do the `return false`? I tried putting `return false` in a AJAX function, but it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code wasn't working is that you were adding an event handler to the event that fires after the alert has already been closed and not the one before it closes. This is what you wanted:

```
$('#myPanel').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
    e.preventPropagation();
});
```

Using `return false;` would also work but I try to use the event methods whenever I can since not all browsers interpret returning `false` from an event handler in the same way.